# Ошибка запуска Webpack

Tags: webpack

При запуске webpack, происходит данная ошибка, как исправить?

[image: ошибка]

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --progress -p",
    "buildDev": "webpack --mode development --progress -p",
    "watch": "webpack --mode production --progress --watch",
    "watchDev": "webpack --mode development --progress --watch"
  },
  "author": "ekrit",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
    "autoprefixer": "^8.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.4",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте в _webpack.config.js_ свойство `output`

Comment: @DiDex вроде бы все в норме там:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/menf3sp4/)

Comment: @DiDex, причем тут output если это optional свойство + ошибка вылетает из-за webpack-cli ?

Comment: @YaroslavKurov, вы используете устаревшую версию `webpack-cli`, с выходом webpack >= 4 - вышел и cli 3 версии, апгрейдните пакет

Comment: @overthesanity да, помогло, спасибо.

Comment: @YaroslavKurov, оформлю тогда как ответ :-))